# c++ char array to char pointer in struct

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a struct containing a char pointer and I have a char array containing data. I would like to have the data within the char array copied to the char pointer.

I have tried strcpy and strncpy but I get a seg fault on both, when trying to copy the data over. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

struct

```
struct Message
{
    Header hdr;
    char *dataArr;
    Footer ftr;
};
```

main

```
int main(){
    // create message struct
    Message send1;

    // create stream
    std::ostringstream outStream;

    //
    // STREAM GETS DATA HERE
    //

    std::string temp = outStream.str();
    char arr[temp.size()];
    strcpy(arr, temp.c_str());
    int sz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char);
    
    // print arr size and contents
    std::cout << "arr size: " << sz << "\n";
    for(int i=0; i<sz; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }

    // copy char array into structs char pointer
    //strncpy(send1.dataArr, arr, sz);
    strcpy(send1.dataArr, arr);   <-- Segmentation fault here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"have the data within the char array copied to the char pointer."* -- can't be done. What you probably mean is "have the data within the char array copied to the *memory to which the char pointer points*." (With that in mind, to what does `send1.dataArr` point?)

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, your issue is at a higher level.  For example, change your design to use `std::string` instead of character pointers or arrays.

Comment: It seems rather wasteful to copy string data to an array (which is one character to small, by the way), then to copy the data from the array. Did you perhaps intend to have `send1.dataArr` point to the data in `arr` instead of making another copy of the data? (If not, why bother with `arr`? How many copies of the data do you need?)

Comment: @JaMiT yes, I intended to have the pointer `send1.dataArr` point to the data inside `std::string temp` or `arr` as they should be the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to allocate memory to copy your data.

Or use [strdup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) that will do it for you